# How to ask a question which is vulnerable to misuse

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I need to ask a question. But the problem is that the notion provided by the question would result in the misuse of the Ask Ubuntu service. What should I do ?
For eg:

- Consider the question [Fake Reputation Scores](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7625/fake-reputation-scores)
  I am sure that reading that question must have induced the generation of some fake accounts, which is the misuse of that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a question like [Fake reputation scores](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7625/fake-reputation-scores), the danger isn't neccessarily in the question. In this case it was in the answer.

But saying that, I personally believe that even if I gave super explicit detail over how the system currently works, it would be almost impossible for a single person to counter and similarly impossible for it to go unnoticed from mods and other users for any reasonable length of time. It's just *easier* to let the chancers hang themselves at the gates before we have to get involved.

I don't think a question like that is going to convince people to cheat... Or convince cheaters not to cheat. It's just an explanation of the system to let non-cheaters and cheaters alike know that we're actively and passively working on detection, punishment and rehabilitation techniques.

---

If your question is about an exploit or bug in the system, I think all the SE sites would appreciate it if you didn't announce it in public! [Responsible disclosure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsible_disclosure) is appreciated.

Use the contact link in the footer, or if you're unsure about whether it's a bug or by design, you could always start a thread on meta asking for a moderator to contact you directly.