# What can I do to improve the reputation of someone (a colleague) that answered my question?

Tags: discussion, users

What can I do to improve the reputation of a colleague, of someone, that answered my question in such a way that the answer is very helpful?
Very probably the only way is to read carefully the documentation of the site.
As a new user of the site, that may take me some time. Thanks.

Comment: You can use [bounties](http://askubuntu.com/help/bounty) to reward someone for helping you, but other than that, no you can't "increase" someone else's reputation. They have to prove that they are good community members themselves.

Comment: Very interesting indeed; and quite complicated. But it is interesting, it can be applied to everyday life.

Answer (score 5):

#### [Guidelines when voting for friends](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5267/guidelines-when-voting-for-friends)

That applies to colleagues, family, friends and people you meet on the street. As soon as you're voting for somebody you know preferentially, you're giving them an unfair advantage over those you don't know.

Additionally we have tools in place to let us know what's going on when people do rig the vote. Please don't set it off.

Comment: Nice to meet you.

Comment: @user295183 Now don't go voting for him ;P