# How to favorite a user?

Tags: discussion, support

We can favorite a question that interests us. Is there a way to favorite a user too?

In order to follow the posts of the user in question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can only subscribe to their RSS feed.

```
http://meta.askubuntu.com/feeds/user/<user_id>
```

The link can be found at the bottom right under their activity tab. The RSS link is called "user feed".

Feature requests about following users, favoring users, adding them to a friend list or anything socially similar [are and will probably always be declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stack-overflow-would-be-nice).

Answer (score 15):

Dan's answer is technically correct in every way but I want to remind you *why* there's no direct way to "follow" somebody on the site. **When you follow people instead of topics, your votes start to become targeted.** It gives your friends an unfair advantage over others just because of *who* they are, not on the merits of their posts' quality.

I've covered this in more detail before: [Guidelines when voting for friends](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5267/guidelines-when-voting-for-friends)

If you are going to follow somebody via their RSS, I would suggest you either prevent yourself from voting, or at least make extra-sure that your votes are warranted, and that you're using the rest of the site normally too. If your account registers a lot of votes for one account, it will raise alarms and may even elicit the fabled *rusty spoon*.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarifications

Comment: I am interested in few users because they always have something new to say ... so may be that will lead to serial upvoting, yes ... which thing is forbidden as you said.

Comment: rusty spoon????

Comment: @Wilf See the last paragraph of [Guidelines when voting for friends](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5267/guidelines-when-voting-for-friends). It's a joke. Probably.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/973/188988) on Meta StackOverflow

> If you have a friends list don't you think you tend to upvote your friends because they are your friends, instead of the content of their posts?

Comment: Thank you for the link