# How can I stalk a user?

Tags: support

Earlier today, I ran across [this user](https://askubuntu.com/users/481799/mc-naveen) who had a few (~5) answers and after a few constructive comments directed to it and removing the [link bait](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/link_bait) from his answers, I suddenly noticed there were only [3 answers](https://askubuntu.com/users/481799/mc-naveen?tab=answers) left...

One I can still find as I still had it [open in a tab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/709866/cannot-install-anything-priveleges) so the question becomes:

*How can I follow this user **including its deleted answers** around for the next couple of days to ensure it is playing by the rules ?*

<sub>*Yes, indeed: the title of this question is also a good example of link bait!*  **;-)**</sub>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to favorite a user?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14135/how-to-favorite-a-user)

Comment: @muru: feed doesn't help: no deleted answers as they're deleted from the feed too...  But it'll help me *stalking* the intelligent users *like you* on the site so I can actually learn something, so thanks for that link anyway!  **:-)**

Answer (score 7):

I'd use [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/) and write a little SQL... Something [like this](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/revision/409603/523686/stalk-a-user):

```
SELECT * FROM Posts
WHERE OwnerUserId IN (449)
AND CreationDate BETWEEN (Getdate() - 14) AND Getdate() 
ORDER BY CreationDate desc
```

Replace my UID `449` with a comma-separated list of UIDs you want to track.

There *is* a delay but for auditing this shouldn't matter. You can do fancy joins on PostTypes to make the output clearer.

Comment: Erm: `SELECT DeletionDate, count(DeletionDate) FROM Posts
WHERE OwnerUserId = 481799
GROUP BY DeletionDate` gives `0`...  Back to composing a [meta.se] question...  **;-)**