# What's a good Enough answer and How

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Ask Ubuntu post: [How to enable Wireshark without running as root in Trusty 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458762/how-to-enable-wireshark-without-running-as-root-in-trusty-14-04/792574#792574)

As a new member at `askubuntu`, Today, I read the above question and I think I can answer it because I'd met it a few months ago, so I'd post my first answer that solved my problem and hope it can help someone else.

The original comments had been deleted by Thomas W. for some security reasons :) , and the I'm waiting for Thomas W. delete my original post,

**so we just return to **

**Discuss:**

- **It's right?** if you think a post is not good enough so you comment it: `It's not right or It's not good` then you just go nether post any reference links or explain why.
- **It's right?** if a post is not right, you can down-vote it but if it is not good enough you down-vote it because you just don't like it.
- **It's right?** if you just want to show your power then call your friends to down-vote the post.

I'd read [How to Answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer), [Don't Ask](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) and [Guidelines when voting for friends](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5267/guidelines-when-voting-for-friends)

Thanks.

Some funny links(not random links, show some guys hands in hands **operating** on the posts ):

- [No more space avbiable even if there are a lot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590315/no-more-space-avbiable-even-if-there-are-a-lot)
- [How do I export a variable to the `sh` shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613215/how-do-i-export-a-variable-to-the-sh-shell/613223)
- [How to change my device name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588210/how-to-change-my-device-name)
- [.nano_history permissions error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617826/nano-history-permissions-error/617830)
- [Import users from CSV file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633695/import-users-from-csv-file/633730)

Comment: @heemayl  topic for you ;)

Comment: You seem to be implying some kind of targeted voting against you here? Don't take it so personally, the votes are against your answer, not you personally and two downvotes is not even a lot. This is your first ever answer here, take the criticism constructively and use it to improve your post. Things can be very informal here, we are not a "chat" site, simple and to the point is the aim, sometimes this can come of as short or even rude but that is not the intention. Don't give up, try again, we all started at the bottom and have bad answers knocking around, it takes time to get it right.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please, do not use random text inside code blocks. :) https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15446/lets-agree-on-some-commonly-accepted-formatting-guidelines

Answer (score 12):

Your post was dangerous. `setuid` bit allows running any application with root privilleges. That means if somebody has way to hack into your computer , they can do whatever they want , because that app has root privillege without asking for password. You can read about it [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14520/what-does-it-mean-to-be-setuid-root) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#Security)

It doesn't matter if you're a new user or not. If that was high-reputation user or even a moderator, it doesn't change the fact that it's dangerous.

Heemayl was a bit too harsh, he should have explained in the comments properly what is the danger of `setuid`. It's a problem that high reputation users sometimes have - we can be quick to judge other people's actions. But the downvotes are proper, because your answer is not a good one for security reasons and because it asks for unnecessary actions.

But trust me: AskUbuntu is a very friendly community and people are more polite here than on other sites. Just get over this, learn more things, and keep posting other answers. You learn as you go—it was the same way for me. Just remember that before you post, ask yourself "Do I really know what this is doing? Is it really safe?"

Also, never argue in the comments. Would you argue with a co-worker in front of customers ? Being professional means solving problems privately and quietly , among other things ; also , remember to seek help from other users - don't try to fight with someone, we're community and supposed to solve issues together

Answer (score 8):

- `sudo chmod u+s which wireshark` seems bad advice to me.
- `sudo reboot now` is not correct. Logging out and in is more than enough. Minor detail though rebooting sometimes can be problematic (due to other services running).
- the highest upvoted answer seems correct already; though not upvoted. All the others seems lacking something or have been deleted due to being harmful.
- https://askubuntu.com/a/461043/15811 compared to https://askubuntu.com/a/461037/15811 seems lacking.

But there is a more serious problem here: This should not have been done with comments. After the 1st comment by heemayl and/or by you both should have stopped discussing it in comments. Use chat or investigate why heemayl said this. From my experience he knows what he is talking so when he picks on me I pay attention to what he said and investigate it ;)